# XDK remote debugging console doesn't work

Tags: remote-debugging, intel-xdk

I have some console.log's in my app, which work fine when viewing the app in a desktop browser. Now, I'm trying to remote-debug the app on a phone, with Intel App Preview. I have launched my app on the phone and clicked "Begin debugging on device" in XDK. This opens up XDK's remote debugging UI, in which I can go to a console. But the console.log's don't get printed on this console. What could be the problem?

BTW I think this used to work for me in the past, just not now.

Answer (score 2):

In order to view the *console.log* messages under the "Debugging Session" console in the TEST tab, you have to copy the provided script tag from the "On Device Debugging" section for insertion after the BODY element.

For example,

**Note:** The src attribute for the script may change when XDK is closed or quitted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:white; color:black }
    </style>
    <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Intel native bridge is available */
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
        //hide splash screen
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        };
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    </script>
    <script>
        function hello(){
            console.log("Hello");
        }
        function windowsize(){
            console.log("Window size Width: " + window.innerWidth + " Height: " + window.innerHeight);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to console log testing</h1>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <button onclick="hello()">Hello_console.log</button>
    <button onclick="windowsize()">Windowsize_console.log</button>
</body>
<script src="http://debug-software.intel.com/target/target-script-min.js#_oDg9dKa6AG4LMdTRJMSDIPU_8Wtj433kqrvyFjcAT4"></script>
</html>
```

After you have included the script tag, you will need to **Push Files** for your project to the Testing servers. When you **scan the QR code**, your application should load as expected. Open the Debugging Session panel by clicking on the **"Begin Debugging on Device" button**. You should see a list of targets and clients. Once you **select the appropriate target**, **click to the Console tab** in the Debugging Session panel to see console.log messages executed when the console is open.

If this still doesn't work for you, I recommend that you uninstall Intel XDK and re-install.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It started working after I reinstalled the XDK. The target list was empty before, and now it's not. BTW I did some things differently. I put the script tag in the body element, not after it. I used local WiFi testing, not the "Push Files" thing. I launched the app by tapping on it, not with the QR code. And it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm, it stopped working again. The targets list is empty again. I restarted the XDK (without reinstalling it this time) and that fixed it. I wonder if I'll have to do this every time.